# Partition SQL Server table by column value

Tags: sql-server

I need to design a SQL Server 2019 database that needs to handle large amount of sensor data. Sensors report data in different data types (int, decimal, bit, string).

I thought to create a table for each data type. Because these tables would increase in size very quickly, a partition would be used on each of data tables.

But I can't figure out what would be the best approach for partitioning?

Is it best to partition by `SensorId` or by `CreatedOn`? Normally users will query data only for one sensor at a time with datetime filters.

What would be best for archiving or deleting old records?

Table design for `Data_Int`:

```
RecordId int
CreatedOn datetime
DeviceId int
SensorId int
SensorValue int
```

Is it possible to create partition by column (`SensorId`) for specific value (like 1) and not by range (1 -2)?

Comment: Sorry for that, it's Microsoft SQL server 2019.

Comment: Maybe not the answer you are looking for but if you are storing sensor data, maybe you should look at time series architectures: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/data-guide/scenarios/time-series#:~:text=Time%20series%20data%20is%20a,stream%20data%2C%20and%20application%20telemetry.

Comment: Thank you, this solution is best i agree, but it's way to expensive for amount of data to be stored.

Comment: If cost is an issue, why use sql server? It’s not exactly cheap. You can use azure table storage and partion on sensorId since the queries will run for 1 sensor.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Because, client has Mssql Enterprise on site. The question is how to correctly design the database to handle such amount of data on MSSQL.

Comment: Do you have an idea how many unique sensor Id's you will have or planning? <1Mil , <10Mil, <100Mil, ...